# In SQL how to return a percentage to 4 decimals

Tags: sql, decimal, rounding

In the below output I have completed subqueries to determine the value of column 1 (Total_Reviews) which is 71 and column 2 (Total_Reviews_Bad) which is 7.

I now want to find the percentage of bad reviews ie. (7*100/71) as a percentage to 4 decimal places.

I am using the round function as per the SQL code below but the output returned is to 1 decimal place and not 4.

Does anyone know why I am getting the answer to only 1 decimal place instead of 4?

```
SELECT 
    Total_Reviews, 
    Total_Reviews_Bad, 
    ROUND(((Total_Reviews_Bad*100)/Total_Reviews),4) AS Percentage
```

FROM
(SELECT
count(review.text) AS Total_Reviews_Open
FROM
review INNER JOIN business
ON
review.business_id = business.id
WHERE
is_open like '%0%'),
(SELECT
count(review.text) AS Total_Reviews_Open_Bad
FROM
review INNER JOIN business
ON
review.business_id = business.id
WHERE
is_open like '%0%' AND review.text like '%bad%')

Output:

| Total_Reviews | Total_Reviews_Bad | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71 | 7 | 9.0 |

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

You have not added from which table you are selecting total_reviews and total_bad_reviews change your query to
select
Total_reviews,
Total_bad_reviews,
from your table name
ROUND(((Total_Reviews_Bad*100)/Total_Reviews),4) AS Percentage